# Go one back browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the web page flow

OTHER pages ... > START page  >  TEAM page > PERSON page

When the user reach the `PERSON page`, how can I make the user to go back to the `START page` instead of going back to the `TEAM page` when the browser back button is pressed?

This is what I tried on the `PERSON page`. But when clicked it doesn't move to the `START page`?

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: You can't override the back button's functionality.

Comment: What's wrong with `window.history.go(-2)`?

Comment: on TEAM page do `location.replace("personpage.html")`

Comment: on hashchange put this 

`window.location.href = 'personpage.html';`

Comment: @mplungjan That will prevent viewing the page. What I need it to be able to skip that page ONLY when the BACK button is pressed.

Comment: You can't, why would you? If I would be user I would be very surprised that I am not going back to the team page when I press back. Why would you like your website to behave differently than others? Ofcourse, you could invent a way with cookies that sets something about the navigation in your page. If you then come to the team page, you could check if the user did the navigation as you think it (team -> person -> team) and redirect them to the start page. But as I said, why make your website behave differently in a browser?

Comment: Of course I meant, when linking to persons page use location.replace instead of location.href or a link. That way the teams page will be replaced in the history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a back button skip a page in the flow, link to the NEXT page using location.replace. So on the team page:

```
$(function() {
  $(".person").on("click",function(e) { // when clicking
   e.preventDefault();
   location.replace(this.href); // replace team page with person page in the history
  });  
});
```

assuming

```
<a href="frank.html" class="person">Frank</a>
<a href="bob.html" class="person">Bob</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, You can check if browser back button is clicked or not and If its clicked redirect it to `Start Page` But Be sure of this because when ever you click back button its always redirect it to your `StartPage`.

Not tested but I think this will do what you want.

```
 window.onpopstate = function(){
    window.location="StartPage";//you page
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it by keeping track of the navigation on your website, as a small example, I wrote this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/s4utu76q/) which checks the navigation and if it conforms to team,person,team it will take the user back to the home page

I guess the main part here would be to handle the navigation of the user yourself and check if it conforms with what you are expecting. To make sure they can then still access the team site, it would also be good that you clear the navigation in the mean time

```
function handleNavigation() {
    var loc = document.location.href.split('#')[1];
    if (!loc) {
        loc = 'home';
    }
    console.log(loc);
    toggleClass(curloc, 'inactive');
    toggleClass(loc, 'inactive');
    if (curloc != loc) {
        tracker.push(loc);
        curloc = loc;
        if (tracker.length > 3) {
            tracker.shift();
        }
        if (tracker.join(',') === 'team,person,team') {
            document.location.replace(document.location.href.split('#')[0]);
            return;
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleNavigation);
window.addEventListener('load', handleNavigation);
```